# How to get location in background without an ongoing notification?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

**Note: I'm using React Native, but this question is specific to Android.**

Since Android 8 (API 26), it's become a bit complicated to get the device's location in the background.

I'm building an app that relies on being able to consistently get the device's location every 10 minutes or so. This includes fetching it in the background.

Based on my reading, there are only a few ways to fetch the device's location in the background now:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits#tuning-behavior

One of the suggestions is to start a foreground service, which has the side effect of presenting an ongoing notification that lets the user know the app is doing something.

For obvious reasons, I don't want my users to see a never-disappearing notification in their notification tray in order for my app to work.

What are my options? Is it still possible to fetch the device's location in the background every 10-or-so minutes?

Thanks.

Comment: It is, you can use a work manager to get it every 15+ minutes, but you need to have location permission (and on Android 30+ users must select Allow all the time instead of Allow while using the app and you should have Background Location permission). In addition, newer androids are kinda extremist when it comes to privacy and if your app does fetch the location in background, it's highly probable that the OS will show a notification telling the user "App X got your location in background". Also, if you're concerned only about the tray, there are some workaround yo snooze your notifications

Comment: @Amin What do you mean by your last sentence, "snooze your notifications"?

Comment: It's a trick, you notify the notification with normal priority, and after a few milliseconds, you notify again but with priority `-2` which is `PRIORITY_MIN` (if I'm not mistaken) and OS will show your notification in "Other Notifications" and does not show notification icon in status bar, [this](https://github.com/QuickLyric/QuickLyric/blob/master/QuickLyric/src/main/java/com/geecko/QuickLyric/utils/NotificationUtil.java) might be an example